# Javascript: calculating remaining time (and then rent) on a tenancy (Rent Calculator)

Tags: javascript

I work at a corporate estate agency and I'm creating an internal page for staff use that will contain just a few small tools for them to use among other things.

One of the things I've been trying to put together is a Rent Calculator, which, given a rental amount and a lease expiry date from the user, needs to determine the time left (from today) on the lease and then advise how much rent is left to pay on that lease.

I've got it working, mostly, but as you can see it's fairly long (I'm assuming to some extent it has to be) and I feel reasonably messy:

```
//calculates the remaining rent left to pay for terminated leases
$("input[name='calcRent']").click(function() {
    //gets rent and daily rent for later calculations
    var rent = $("input[name='rentRent']").val();
    var dailyRate = (rent * 12) / 365;
    var leaseExpiry = $("input[name='leaseExpiry']").val();
    var remRent = $("input[name='remRent']");
    //breaks down lease expiry date and today's date into day, month, year parts
    //so that units can be used in calculations
    var ldd = leaseExpiry.substr(0,2);
        ldd = parseInt(ldd, 10);
    var lmm = leaseExpiry.substr(3,2);
        lmm = parseInt(lmm, 10);
    var lyyyy = leaseExpiry.substr(6,4);
        lyyyy = parseInt(lyyyy, 10);
    var date = new Date();
    var tdd = date.getDate();
    var tmm = date.getMonth()+1;
    var tyyyy = date.getFullYear();
        //if the expiry month is next year (or later) add 12 to expiry
        //month value to make "lmm - tmm" calculation give positive value
        if (lyyyy > tyyyy) {
            lmm += (12 * (lyyyy - tyyyy));
        }
    //takes the current month from the expiry month to get the number of
    //whole months left in the lease, then checks day values to see whether
    //we have already passed the rent due date for this month (and so there's
    //one less whole month left than we originally thought), taking 1 from
    //wholeMths value if so
    var wholeMths = lmm - tmm;
        if (ldd == (tdd - 1)) {
            wholeMths = wholeMths;
        } else if (ldd < (tdd - 1)) {
            wholeMths -= 1;
        }
    //works out if there are any days to be charged at daily rate (i.e. not
    //part of a whole month). If today's date(tdd) == expiry date(ldd)+1 we have no
    //leftover days (rental month runs like so: 12/04 - 11/05). If tdd > ldd+1
    //(leftover days cross over a month end) we set checkMonth to true so the following
    //if statement runs
    var checkMonth = false;
    var daysLeft = 0;
        if (tdd == (ldd + 1)) {
            daysLeft = 0;
        } else if (tdd > ldd + 1) {
            daysLeft = (31 - tdd) + ldd;
            checkMonth = true;
        } else {
            daysLeft = ldd - tdd;
        }
        //as per the above line: "daysLeft = (31 - tdd) + ldd;" we assume months have 31 days
        //as the majority do, this if checks whether the month end that we cross over with our
        //leftover days actually has 30 days, if not we check whether it's February and whether
        //it's a leap year so that we get the appropriate no. of days to charge for - if it meets
        //any of these criteria the relevant no. of days are subtracted from daysLeft
        if ((lmm == 05 || lmm == 07 || lmm == 10 || lmm == 12
            || lmm == 17 || lmm == 19 || lmm == 22 || lmm == 24) && checkMonth) {
            daysLeft -= 1;
        } else if ((lmm == 03 || lmm == 15) && checkMonth) {
            if (lyyyy % 4 == 0) {
                daysLeft -= 2;
            } else {
                daysLeft -= 3;
            }
        }
        checkMonth = false;
    var balance = (wholeMths * rent) + (daysLeft * dailyRate);

    remRent.val(balance.toFixed(2));        
});
```

One of the bits that's especially bugging me is where the lease expiry occurs in a subsequent year. I haven't got my head round how to tidily deal with the 'value' of that month (as you can see in the final if).

Any suggestions on this would be appreciated as the number and volume of the comments seem a bit disproportionate to the actual code - but I think they're necessary at the moment as it's not too clear what's going on.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) can help you.

Comment: I'm getting XY problem on this. I see your code, I see more or less what you are trying to achieve, but since you didn't really ask a question, and because I only see the final code and not the original 'specification calculations' I can't really easily determine whether you've created good code or not.

Comment: moment.js looks like it may be handy in cutting down the size a bit, thanks.

Niels - the only data provided outside of the code is the monthly rental price, and the date on which the tenancy is due to end, the output is simply a number (the amount of rent left to pay from today to the above mentioned date). I've got no problem with the data coming, and it is outputting the balance, but as above my main concern is around the final if being a bit messy, where the lease expiry date is in the year after the one we're currently in, and whether there's a better way to figure that all out?

Answer (score 1):

Good work on what you have done, but you need to take advantage of the built-in date calculations available in JavaScript using the `Date` class.

Specifically to get the number of days between to dates you can use the following logic:

```
var currentDate = new Date();    // This will get today's date
currentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);   // Remove time from consideration
                                 // As recommended by @NickSlash

// The following get's the lease expiration date using the year,
// month and date that you have already extracted from the input
var leaseExpirationDate = new Date( lyyyy, lmm, ldd ); 

// The number of days remaining in the lease is simply the following:
var one_day = 1000*60*60*24;
var daysLeftInLease = (leaseExpirationDate - currentDate ) / one_day;
```

This magic happens because internally the `Date` class keeps the date value as the number milliseconds since 1/1/1970.  Therefore if you subtract two `Date` objects you get the number of milliseconds between them.  You can then simply divide that value by the number of milliseconds in one day to get the number of days between the dates.

Comment: Keep in mind that many of the complex calculations in the original code actually result from not **wanting** to do unix-timestamp-based calculations. Rent usually is paid on a monthly basis, and so a lot of the calculation needs to know that January 15th and March 15th are "two months apart", not "59 or 60 days depending on the leap year".

Comment: The function (in the question) returns (or sets) one result which is the remaining rent, how its calculated is irrelevant, I was about to suggest the same answer, beat me to it :D Might want to add `currentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);` or round the number so the current time doesnt affect the result.

Comment: I think Niels is right - because rent is charged monthly (which != daily rate, otherwise the monthly rent wouldn't be the same for all 12 months - it only goes to a daily rate when it's not a whole month), calculating it like this gives the incorrect figures e.g. tried it at: rent = 100; lease expiry = 11/03/2014; and I got 1094.89 where it should have been a round 1000.

Annoying because it cut the code down a lot :)